# K theory of suspension of the disjoint union

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory, k-theory

I wonder why it is true that $\widetilde{K^0}(S(X \sqcup \{*\}))=\widetilde{K^0}(SX) \oplus \widetilde{K^0}(S^1)$ where $SX$ is the suspension of $X$ and $\widetilde{K^0}$ is reduced $K^0$ group.

Comment: The K-theory of a wedge is the direct sum of the K-theories.

Comment: So I need to know whether $S(X \sqcup \{*\})=SX \wedge S^1$: I would guess that this is true for reduces suspension. Somewhere I read that the reduced suspension is homotopy equivalent to unreduced one (at least in the category of CW complexes). Am I right?

Comment: *Weakly* homotopy equivalent for CW complexes. Note that reduced K-theory of a circle is zero.

Comment: But for CW complexes we have Whitehead theorem which gives that weak homotopy equivalence implies homotopy equivalence, right?

Comment: Yes, but note you need to prove that suspending keeps you inside CW complexes (which is true and easy).